# Bootstrap buttons/input fields on same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to recreate this example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups-buttons-multiple

[image]

Why if I copy this example, with the exact same code I see while inspecting elements, the buttons and input fields are not on the same line?

[image]

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <form class="bs-example bs-example-form" data-example-id="input-group-multiple-buttons"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with multiple buttons">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Help"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxae9L36/1/).

Comment: This is the HTML from the page you should've copied `<div class="input-group"> <input class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with multiple buttons"> <div class="input-group-btn"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Help"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button> </div> </div>`

Comment: I don't know how you can say " the exact same code I see while inspecting elements" when it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your column and input group reversed. Typically all content should be inside the column, and the only children of a row should be columns.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/z8f1yu0n/)**